# Not understanding numpy code from a book

Tags: python, numpy

```
X = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 0]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
counts = {}
for label in np.unique(y):
     counts[label] = X[y == label].sum(axis=0)
print("Feature counts: ", counts)'
```

This code is meant to check for the number of times a feature of a class is not zero, however I do not understand the syntax `counts[label] = X[y == label].sum(axis=0)`. When I simply run `print(y==label)`, the numpy array `[False  True False  True]` is presented and I do not understand how this indexes and sums item in the numpy array. Further, I do not understand why `y==label' has been set.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is a classic group-by operation; which sadly numpy does not provide in an elegant way out of the box. You seem less concerned with a high-level understanding than with a low level understanding; but if the latter is infact not a goal in itself, there are alternatives that abstract these worries away from you, such as [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/tree/master/numpy_indexed) (disclaimer: I am its author)

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
labels, counts = npi.group_by(y).sum(X)
```

Which will do the same thing, but in a vectorized and thus much more scalable manner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code is doing non zero element check. for you other part of question. y == 1 would give you a boolean mask

if you want to check non-zero, call unique function and remove zero element count

```
np.unique(X, return_counts=True)
(array([0, 1]), array([8, 8], dtype=int64))# first array is element, second is count
```

boolean mask example:

```
print y
[0 1 0 1]
```

this will compare all element in y with 1 and return a true/false list

```
print y == 1
[False  True False  True]
```

based on the above true/false list, it selects row 1 and 3 from X

```
print X[y == 1]
[[1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me how it selects rows 1 and 3 from X using a true False list.

Comment: @SamarthUpadhyaya y == 1 return [False  True False  True], so the second and forth element in list are true, therefore the second and forth get to select